# phonegap platform add osx fails

Tags: macos, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have an existing ios app that I made using phonegap. I would like to publish it in the Mac App store, but I'm falling at the first hurdle.

I run `phonegap platform add osx` and I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to fetch platform osx
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: No compatible version found: cordova-osx@'>=4.0.0 <4.1.0'
Valid install targets:
["3.4.1"]
```

I'm connected to the internet (if that's what the `connection problem` is hinting at), and I'm not sure exactly what `platform spec is invalid` means.

I have phonegap version `5.3.8` installed, and `cordova --version` shows `4.0.0`

Comment: Why are you trying to publish an ios app in the mac app store?

Comment: The same code is already available in the Windows store and on Android. The app is perfectly appropriate for a desktop environment and uses responsive styling so it looks as good on Desktop as it does on iOS

Answer (score 0):

The OSX platform is not officially released yet and not pushed to npm.
Currently you need to add it via the git url:

```
cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx.git
```

See the [readme](https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx/blob/master/README.md) on the cordova-osx github page for more information.